# too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed

Tags: python, excel, csv, error-handling

I am very beginner of the using Python codes. I would appreciate if anyone can help me for my question. I run the codes given below to generate data and split the test and train data. And I get train data 200 rows and 2 columns but I get test data 100 rows and 1 column. I don't understand why train data has 2 columns and test data is 1 column.

At the end, this problem cause the problem

> too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed

when I run the code part given right below.

```
feature_1_test = X_test[:,[0]].reshape(-1,1)
feature_2_test = X_test[:,[1]].reshape(-1,1) 

import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pyod.models.knn import KNN
from pyod.utils.data import generate_data
outlier_fraction = 0.1  
n_train = 200 
n_test = 100
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = generate_data(n_train=n_train, n_test=n_test, contamination=outlier_fraction)

#plot train and test set
feature_1_train = X_train[:,[0]].reshape(-1,1)
feature_2_train = X_train[:,[1]].reshape(-1,1)
feature_1_test = X_test[:,[0]].reshape(-1,1)
feature_2_test = X_test[:,[1]].reshape(-1,1)
```

I really appreciate for your help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the 'pyod' documents, the function 'generate_data' returns in a different order. That's why you have that dimension problem. You can check the function parameters and returns by visiting this [page.](https://pyod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyod.utils.html#pyod.utils.data.generate_data) Below, you can see the version I successfully managed to run.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pyod.models.knn import KNN
from pyod.utils.data import generate_data


outlier_fraction = 0.1  
n_train = 200 
n_test = 100
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = generate_data(n_train=n_train, n_test=n_test, contamination=outlier_fraction)

print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)


#plot train and test set
feature_1_train = X_train[:,[0]].reshape(-1,1)
feature_2_train = X_train[:,[1]].reshape(-1,1)
feature_1_test = X_test[:,[0]].reshape(-1,1)
feature_2_test = X_test[:,[1]].reshape(-1,1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much... I really appreciate for it, I couln't further without solving the problem.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Use documentation for every function. They are very helpful